# Using a user defined simpletype in an XSD document

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to modify the XSD code below to include a user defined simpleType. The code is generated by Visual Studio. When I try to refer to the LimitedString type in the last line the parser tells me that the type is undefined. How do I fix this?

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="LimitedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="BRSTAG">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="INSTRUMENTS">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="INSTRUMENT"> 
                <xs:complexType>              
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CUSIP" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Hello BruceG!  Could you post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: When I change the type in the last line from "string" to "LimitedString" I get "XMLSchema:LimitedString is not declared"

Comment: The schema that you have supplied is not a valid XSD (closing tags are missing). Please supply a minimal example of a _complete_ schema that produces this error.

Comment: There are a total 250 columns that are defined in this XSD.  I deliberately only included the first 50 lines because they are the relevant ones. The file as a whole is a valid XSD that is automatically generated by SSIS.  Please concentrate on the lines supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce your issue with the example you have given.
After adding all the ending tags, which were missing from your example (hence it being invalid), I was able to reference the LimitedString type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="LimitedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="BRSTAG">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="INSTRUMENTS">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="INSTRUMENT">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CUSIP" type="LimitedString" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```